# About regexp performancing

Tags: regex

Given string `ab`

given this regex pattern

```
(a)(b)
```

If we need remove full string, but print second group, we can write 2 variant:

1) `preg_replace("#(a)(b)#", "$2", "ab") // save both group`

and also so:

2) `preg_replace("#(?:a)(b)#", "$1", "ab") // dont save first group`

What variant better for performance?

Comment: Hi, I have removed the second question. You can still ask it in a separate post. You should ask only 1 question per post.

Comment: Also is this a PHP question? I'll retag it as such.

Comment: The second is supposedly faster.. But from this overly simplistic example, `"#a(b)#", "$1"` would be even better I believe.

Comment: Why not run a simple test and see which is faster yourself?

Comment: sashoalm --- Not only php question, about regex  in any language, php is just for  exmple.

FabrícioMatté --- Yes, but my question is: when we need croup both part, but need save just second, what variant is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran each operation in a tight loop 5,000,000 each and compared the times.  I actually compared four operations:

```
preg_replace("#(a)(b)#", "$2", "ab");
preg_replace("#(?:a)(b)#", "$2", "ab");
preg_replace("#a(b)#", "$2", "ab");
preg_replace("#a(?=b)#", "", "ab");
```

I didn't see a very consistent difference in the times, so I think that it actually doesn't matter much for performance, i.e. I would choose whichever makes the most sense from a design / semantic perspective.

#1 and #2 performed about the same.  #2 seems slightly faster, but occassionally slower (probably due to server noise).  #3 is consistently about 5% faster than that, and option #4 is about 2% faster than #3 (i.e. it seems to be the best, probably because it doesn't have to capture or interpolate anything).

Still, I'd just go with what makes the most sense.

I realize that `str_replace("ab", "b", "ab");` may not be analogous, but use it if you can.  It's consistently more than twice as fast as any of the others.

Comment: @OTARIKI yes; I reran the tests a few times, and it doesn't seem to make that much of a difference.

Comment: Oh my english... :) I mean that you, in #2 example, in `replacement` have `$2`, but you mean here `$1`, right? :) Thanks very much for answer

Answer (score 0):

> What variant better for performance?

Either.

In case you have to do only few replacements, it wouldn't matter at all.
In case you have to do millions of replaces, you have to consider another format for the source data, which will require less parsing.

But anyway, nowadays computers are FAST. I mean FAST.
Fast enough to run JSON- or XML-based applications while JSON or XML parsing require WAY more resources than simple regexp in question. And they runs well. So, I doubt you will face a condition where such a regexp will affect *anything*